# Error message in fortran (Optimizing routine)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am using fortran and I have the following error message:
undefined reference to `newuoa_h_'
does anyone know how to run NEWUOA_H(n,npt,x,rhobeg,rhoend,iprint,maxfun,w,mv) in fortran?

thanks

Comment: Supposing it is not a subroutine in your code, I imagine a library link is necessary. How are you compiling your code?

Comment: I use ifortran to compile

Comment: Okay...what **commands** do you enter to compile?

Comment: Do you mean `ifort`, or `gfortran`?  There is no `ifortran` to my knowledge.  This will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing function seems to be [here](https://code.google.com/p/otkpp/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fexperimental%2Fotkpp%2Fsolvers%2Fnewuoa) in the [otkpp](http://code.google.com/p/otkpp/) optimization library.

You may have to install it, or at list to extract the functions you need (there is a C++ wrapper, but the algorithms are written in Fortran).

By the way, if you use also LMBM, there is a note on [Napsu Karmitsa's site](http://napsu.karmitsa.fi/lmbm/) (the author) which is not on Google groups: *The software is free for academic teaching and research purposes but I ask you to refer at least one of the references given below if you use it*". I don't know who wrote newuoa, but otkpp itself is under GPLv3, and it's author, Seppo Pulkkinen, is a student under Karmitsa's supervision (see [here](http://tucs.fi/education/phd/supervisors/supervisor.php?supervisor=66)).

**edit**

After more search, it appears newuoa has been written by [M. J. D. Powell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_J._D._Powell) (a numerical analyst well known in the optimization field), now retired. The source code is also [here](http://www.inrialpes.fr/bipop/people/guilbert/newuoa/newuoa.html), in Fortran together with an f2c translation. The fortran code is "*totally free*" according to this site.